# Android onLocationChanged GPSTracker crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to send the longitude and latitude from my `onLocationChanged` method inside the class `GPSTracker` to `GPSPrincipal` (Which is my main activity) and activate a toast that shows the longitude and latitude.

I'm having problems with the broadcastreciver to send the data from GPSTracker to GPSPrincipal, also, the aplication crashes and it shows the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:344)
>   at
>   co.edu.javeriana.introcm.gpsexample.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:192)

The line 192 is:

```
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Last line on `onLocationChanged` inside `GPSTracker`

GPSPrincipal (Main activity):

```
public class GPSPrincipal extends Activity {
    GPSTracker gps;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsprincipal);
    }

    public void loca(View arg0) {
        gps = new GPSTracker(GPSPrincipal.this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){
            TextView latitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showLatitud);
            TextView longitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showLongitud);
            latitud.setText(String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()));
            longitud.setText(String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()));}
        else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();}
    }

    public void cambio () {
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Located: - \nLat: " + intent.getExtras().get("latitude") + "\nLong: " + intent.getExtras().get("longitude"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}};
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.broadcast.gps.location_change"));
    }    }
```

GPSTracker:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private Location location;
    private double latitude; // latitud
    private double longitude; // longitud

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context; //Obtener el contexto
        getLocation();
   }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.example.broadcast.gps.location_change");
        broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
package="co.edu.javeriana.introcm.gpsexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".GPSPrincipal"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Potentially seems to be that your context when calling sendBroadcast() is null within the ContextWrapper class. Perhaps you should try using mContext.sendBroadcast and see if that makes a differencew

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said and it works.

Comment: Good to hear, I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially seems to be that your context when calling sendBroadcast() is null within the ContextWrapper class. Perhaps you should try using mContext.sendBroadcast and see if that makes a difference.